# VBA in MS Word affects whole document, not just selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to have a VBA script perform a find / replace in a selection and then assign the macro to a button on the Quick Access ToolBar, to save having to click through the usual Find/Replace procedure.

I recorded a macro while doing this and this is what I get:

```
 Sub FindReplace()
      '
      ' FindReplace Macro
      '
      '
     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
     Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
     With Selection.Find
         .Text = "^p"
         .Replacement.Text = " "
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindAsk
         .Format = False
         .MatchCase = False
         .MatchWholeWord = False
         .MatchWildcards = False
         .MatchSoundsLike = False
         .MatchAllWordForms = False
     End With
     Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 End Sub
```

But when I run this macro on a selection to change paragraph marks into spaces it continues on to change the whole document, not just the selection.

I'm no stranger to VBA but I can't see how to fix it so it stops when the selection is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to use

```
     .Wrap = wdFindStop
```

Instead of

```
     .Wrap = wdFindAsk
```

Comment: @Helen269 Good Stuff, just remember to upvote the answer you select as appropriate as well.